# Проверка существования окна по заголовку

Tags: c#

Каким образом проверить существование окна в Windows (не главное) из всех существующих главных и дочерних окон ?

Comment: Окна вашего приложения или любого окна?

Comment: @tym32167 как я понял, чтобы найти дочернее, нужно сначала знать главное, мне бы хотелось получить список заголовков абсолютно всех существующих окон главных и дочерних в Windows и в нем уже проверять на существование того которое мне нужно.

Comment: [это?](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/EnumDesktopWindows.html)

Comment: @tym32167 да, как раз ковыряю, спасибо !